# What is the simplest way to integrate PayPal Express Checkout on an Angular JS/Rails API app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, api, paypal

I've got this Angular App which is fuelled by a Rails API. As part of the setup I needed to add Stripe payments for debit/credit cards and PayPal for people who wanted to their PayPal account.

Stripe was a breeze to setup (thanks to a straight forward API and proper documentation) while PayPal is turning out to be the exact opposite.

Starting with their documentation, it is very unclear what methods to use, but after a lot googling the best way forward seems to be sticking with Express Checkout (remember this is just for users who will pay using their PayPal accounts).

It seems I can't do a `SetExpressCheckout` call via the Angular App directly because I'm getting a CORS error.

So, my question is: Is at all possible to initiate the process via the Angular App or do I need to do it through my Rails API?

If I have to do through the API, is there a tutorial out there anyone can recommend? I've tried those:

- https://launchschool.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails,
- https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-ruby,
- https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-ruby,
- https://anadea.info/blog/paypal-classic-api-and-rails-how-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot,
- https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

Whenever I tried any of the above, I got stuck at one point or another. before pursuing any of the aforementioned approaches further, I'd like to know whether I'm on the right path, so I'd REALLY appreciate if someone could pinpoint whether using the Express Checkout is the best approach and whether is definitely not possible initiate the process (get the token) through Angular. Lastly if there's recent and complete tutorial out there would also be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular code example directive here: https://github.com/twler/angular-paypal-checkout